# Unknown grammar: でいたい structure

Tags: grammar

> 友達でいたいと考えた。

What do you guys make of this でいたい structure?

I have never come across it before.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to JLSE. Please avoid giving your question vague titles. The title should give users an idea of what the question is about before they click it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you will understand it better split up:
`友達` + `で` + `いたい`

Now `いたい` is referring to `居たい`, which you could interpret as meaning `to exist`. So, a rough translation would be `Want to exist (居たい)` + `as (で)` + `friend (友達)`.

A better translation while also adding the `と考えた` part would be:

> I thought about staying as friends.

I could see someone saying this after they break up with their partner and they thought about still hanging out with them, but just as friends instead of lovers.

The `で居たい` form is pretty common though so I would recommend remembering it.

For example,

> いつも笑顔でいたい ⇒ I always want to stay smiling
>
> 私は独身でいたい ⇒ I always want to stay single

I would add the `always` in English because when using `居たい` it does not refer to a temporary thing.